# What are the best practices when designing restricted areas in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, devise, authorization

being newish to rails I wanted to get some advice from the community on how to setup restricted areas. I just started using Devise and have read about a few different methods for redirecting/rendering views based on if a user is logged in or not and I'm wondering what the best way to go about it is.

Currently, when I want a logged in user to have a different view of a page then a non-logged in user I've been handling it in the controller. For instance:

```
class CollectionsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
    @collections = Collection.all

    if current_user
      render :admin
    else
      render :index
    end
  end
end
```

In which case `:admin` and `:index` correspond to `views/collections/admin.html.haml` and `views/collections/index.html.haml` respectively. The admin view is similar in layout to the index view but has links to the edit, update, create, etc.

Is this the best way going about it?

EDIT: I was also considering trying out an authorization gem like CanCan but wasn't sure if that would be overkill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you check out [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) if you want to keep your code nice and DRY -the way you're currently doing it will lead to lots of repeated code and might become unmanageable.
Once installed, CanCan will generate an 'Ability' file where you can define what users can or cannot do. in you case for example, you might have

```
def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    if user.admin?
      can :manage, :all
    else
      can :read, :all
    end
  end
```

Then in your views, you can do a simple check to see whether or not a user has the ability to modify that object. For instance:

```
<% if can? :create, Project %>
  <%= link_to "New Project", new_project_path %>
<% end %>
```

It's a super useful gem and very well documented!

Comment: I decided to go with CanCan and it's great! Really easy to implement and use.

Comment: My only question about this method is, since is it kosher to have that kind of logic in a view if one is trying to be as MVC as possible?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of duplicating view code for admin and guest users and maintain them separately, you can just have one view `index.html.haml` and display the links to edit, update and create etc. only if `current_user` is not nil or for that matter admin.

In your view:

```
- if current_user 
  = link_to 'Edit', edit_path
  = link_to 'Update', update_path
```

and in your `CollectionController`

```
def index
  @collections = Collection.all
end
```

This way you don't need to maintain two separate views and you can get rid of the `admin.html.haml`.

Yes, if you have many different places where you need to implement these sorts of logic then implementing CanCan gem as suggested by @Anchor would probably be the way to go.